# Counting occurrences of the first x elements of sublist in all sublists of the jagged list without grouping

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, jagged-arrays

I'm having a jagged list.

```
var jaggedList = new List<List<string>>()
{ cc kk ww }
{ cc kk aa }
{ cc oo ll }
{ cc jj oo }
{ ww oo kk }
{ ww oo gg }
{ ww gg kk }
{ kk ll oo }
{ ll kk nn }
{ mm nn oo }
{ mm nn jj }
```

I'm also having a LINQ command that does what I want but with grouping.

```
var dic = jaggedList.GroupBy(lst => string.Join(" ", lst.Take(2))) 
                    .ToDictionary(el => el.Key, el => el.Count());
```

Now I want this command edited so it would not group.

Comment: Why you don't want to use `GroupBy`?

Comment: Because i need this "dic" variable to have the same count as the jaggedList.Count(). Sorry if that made this thing harder.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that it is what you want, please check it:

P.S. Now dic variable is not actually dictionary, because if you want same count as jaggedList, there will be key dublicates that is inadmissible for dictionary collection.

```
    var n = 2;

    var jaggedList = new List<List<string>>(){
            new List<string>{ "cc", "kk", "ww" },
            new List<string>{ "cc", "kk", "aa" },
            new List<string>{ "cc", "oo", "ll" },
            new List<string>{ "cc", "jj", "oo" },
            new List<string>{ "ww", "oo", "kk" },
            new List<string>{ "ww", "oo", "gg" },
            new List<string>{ "ww", "gg", "kk" },
            new List<string>{ "kk", "ll", "oo" },
            new List<string>{ "ll", "kk", "nn" },
            new List<string>{ "mm", "nn", "oo" },
            new List<string>{ "mm", "nn", "jj" }
    };

    Func<IEnumerable<string>, int, string> getKey = (col, num) => col.Take(num).Aggregate((a, b) => a + " " + b);

    var dic = jaggedList.Select(x => {
        var key = getKey(x, n);
        return new { 
            key,
            count = jaggedList.Where(y => getKey(y, n) == key).Count()
        };
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Some guy edited my post, probably thats why you did not hit the answer.
It should be "int x=2" above it so i would change it whenever i want and in that linq command it should be "lst.Take(x)" instead of "lst.Take(2)". Thanks for your time and effort though.

Comment: BTW you were right with one thing. It does not have to be a dictionary.